# find vector x so that vector: diag(x).C.x has all components equal, where C is positive-definite

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, polynomials

PROBLEM: I am trying to find closed form solutions or provable general properties of solutions for the solution $x$ of the following:
Find $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_N \end{bmatrix}$ where:
 $$diag(x) C x == \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ \vdots \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

...(or more generally equals $\begin{bmatrix} t \\ \vdots \\ t \end{bmatrix}$ for any positive constant $t>0$).

The solution, $x$, is an $N$-by-1 (column) vector.  The right hand side, the column vector of ones, is as well.

$C$ is an $N$-by-$N$ correlation matrix: it is symmetric, the diagonal elements are exactly $1$, and the off-diagonal elements are in the range $-1 < C(j,k) < 1$.  Actually for my problem we can assume $0 < C(j,k) < 1$, for all $j \ne k$.

We should assume $N>3$ and $C(j,k)$ is distinct for every distinct combination $(j,k)$ where $j \ne k$.  I have found easy solutions for $N=2$, and where all the off-diagonal elements have the same value.

I am using the convention $M=diag(x)$ to refer to the diagonal square matrix $M$ with whose diagonal is formed by the vector $x$, that is, $M_{j,j} = x_j$.

This problem involves (a) simultaneous polynomial equations, and (b) positive definite matrices (more specifically nonsingular correlation matrices).  I am trying to find either a closed form solution (which may not exist) or at least to find if this family of equations has “a name” and some well-known properties within some sub field of algebra.  It started out as a signal / data viz problem I got obsessed with after working on it in 2 & 3 variable problems, and realized there wasn't (?) a solution for higher dimensions that was easy/obvious (to me at least).

Anything you got is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No closed form: basically isomorphic to finding a general closed-form solution for the roots of polynomials of arbitrarily high degree.  It is however frequently solved by numerical optimization in applications such as the determination of so-called "risk parity" portfolios in finance.

Answer (score 0):

I am very much interested in knowing if you made any progress on this question. See my question here: [How to solve $\mathrm{diag}(x) \; A \; x = \mathbf{1}$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655280/how-to-solve-a-x-1-x-for-x-in-mathbbrn-with-a-in-mathbbrn-time).